# Im confused about something of makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu

what do $(MAKE) and $(MAKEFILES) do

some tutorials say that we'd better not use the variable MAKEFILES, and i dont know why.
hope someone can explain, thx.

Comment: The `MAKE` variable is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) and the `MAKEFILES` variable is explaine [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKEFILES-Variable).

Comment: i had read them before i asked the question.but my english is poor.i cant understand the translation as well

Comment: thx my problem solved